# Ubuntu 22.10 super slow and laggy

Tags: performance, amd-processor, 22.10

I was running ubuntu 22.04 in my laptop (which was really fast) and upgraded to 22.10 today morning.
Since the upgrade, the CPU is running very high and the system lags like crazy.

My system has AMD 4650U CPU and 24GB ram.

Comment: Any particular process causing this? (I have a similar issue on Kubuntu 22.10 with XOrg, which you are not using if on vanilla Ubuntu)

Comment: I tried with XOrg and the default display driver. Both are slow. In general all processes are taking more CPU, `htop` is consuming 45% CPU. VS Code is ususeably slow.

Comment: In my case it is caused by the process xembednissproxy. When killing this, all other processes behave normal. If I dont kill it most processes get >20 and Xorg gets to 100. But this is on KUbuntu with Xorg (on wayland I do not have the problem)

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. Both under Xorg and Wayland. I can't tell what the issue might be because the mouse freezes for 30 seconds or more. When it come back and I bring up a terminal, top shows the system is idle. I'm running an 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12950HX with 64GB memory. Its not a lack of CPU or memory.

Answer (score 0):

I put my system to sleep and then woke it up again and it is back to normal.

This is a Lenovo Thinkpad E14 notebook, I am already facing an issue with this laptop where the function keys will not work on boot. I have to suspend and turn it back on for it to work. So the same solution worked for this issue as well.